# Show the collection of subsets is a basis.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Here is my attempt at showing this collection forms a basis. Have I done all the necessary cases? Is this correct?

Problem:We construct a topological space. Let $\mathbb{R}_{+00}$ be the set consisting of $\mathbb{R}_+$ together with two points called $0'$ and $0''$. Put a topology on it generated by a basis consisting of all intervals in $\mathbb{R}_+$ of the form $(a,b)$ or else of the form $(0,b) \cup \{0'\}$ or $(0,b) \cup \{0''\}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Show this collection of sets forms a basis for a topology.

Attempt:
Each point in $\mathbb{R}_{+00}$ is in at least one basis element. If $x \in \mathbb{R_+}$,the basis element $(0,x+1) \cup \{0'\}$ certainly contains $x$. $0' \in (0,b) \cup \{0'\}$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R_+}$ and $0'' \in (0,b) \cup \{0''\}$ for any $b \in \mathbb{R_+}$. The intersection of any two open intervals $(a,b),(c,d),a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R_+},a<b,c<d$  is either $\varnothing$, or a basis element. If  $a<b$ and $x \in ((0,a) \cup \{0'\}) \cap ((0,b) \cup \{0''\})$, choose $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<x$. Then $x\in (x-\epsilon,a)  \subset ((0,a) \cup \{0'\}) \cap ((0,b) \cup \{0''\})$. The case where $b>a$ is similar. $(c,d) \cap ((0,a) \cup \{0'\})$ is either $\varnothing$ or an open interval of the form  $(e,f)$, a basis element. Similarly for $(c,d) \cap ((0,a) \cup \{0''\}).$

Comment: Looks nice for me.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume $0',0''$ are distinct negative points?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I am not sure, it just says two made up points.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: No, they are simply two new points not in $\Bbb R_+$. The topology generated by this base makes each of the subsets $\Bbb R_+\cup\{0'\}$ and $\Bbb R_+\cup\{0''\}$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ with the usual topology; the space as a whole is the [line with two origins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709777/the-line-with-two-origins) minus the negative reals.

Comment: @ScottFrazier If you don't know that $0',0''\le0$, how does your second last line make sense?

Comment: If $B$ is a family of subsets of a set $X$ then $B$ is a base (basis) for a topology on $X$ iff $(i) \,\cup B=X\,$(i.e. every member pf $X$ belongs to at least one $b\in B$), and $(ii)$ whenever $b,b'\in B$ and $x\in b\cap b',$ there exists $b''\in B$ with $x\in b''\subseteq b\cap b'.$ Of course if $b\cap b'\in B$ whenever $b,b'\in B$ then $(ii)$ is satisfied by $b''=b\cap b'$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I do not mean to be rude, but I thought those conditions are what I have shown.Where did I go wrong? At least that is what I have tried to show.

Comment: You aren't wrong. I just wanted to state the general case. Some other students get the mistaken notion that a base must be closed under finite intersections

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the sign of $0',0''$, your assumption that $(c,d)\cap[(0,a)\cup\{0'\}]$ being either empty or an open interval is incorrect. Note that it is equal to$$A=[(c,d)\cap(0,a)]\color{pink}\cup[(c,d)\cap\{0'\}]=(\max\{0,c\},\min\{a,d\})\color{pink}\cup[(c,d)\cap\{0'\}]$$where the former is an open interval (including the empty set) and the latter may give you an isolated point $0'$ in case $0'$ is positive. In this case there is no basis element containing $0'$ which is a subset of $A$ unless $c=0$. For example, $(c,d)=(5,15),(0,a)\cup\{0'\}=(0,6)\cup\{12\}$.

So you must remark that the given set forms a basis iff $0',0''\le0$.

---

For $a<b$,$$[(0,a) \cup \{0'\}] \cap[(0,b) \cup \{0''\}]=(0,a)\color{pink}\cup[\{0'\}\cap\{0''\}]$$There is a possibility that this intersection contains the point $0'$ iff $0'=0''$, in which case $(0'-\epsilon,a)$ is not be a suitable choice. For $0'$, select the basis element  $(0,a)\cup\{0'\}$ and you are done.

Comment: It says in the book that $0'$ and $0''$ are not points in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Comment: @ScottFrazier Should have mentioned that earlier. Now you know why $0',0''$ must be non-positive ;) The second part of my solution still applies to your answer.