# How do we “directly” show that the cofinite space $\Bbb N$ is not weak-Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $\Bbb N$ be equipped with the cofinite topology: call this space $X$.

> Definition: a topological space $Y$ is *weak-Hausdorff* (WH) iff. for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and continuous $\nu:K\to Y$, $\nu(K)$ is closed in $Y$.

This is quite a mysterious property (in my opinion) which seems hard to verify in general. But we are lucky here: unless I’m crazy, $X$ is in fact a compact space and as such it is compactly generated (CG):

> Definition: a space $Y$ is *compactly generated* iff. a $U\subseteq Y$ is closed iff. for all compact Hausdorff spaces $K$ and continuous $\nu:K\to Y$, $\nu^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $K$ (this property of such $U$ is called “$k$-closed”.)

And it turns out that, given a CG space $Y$, we can canonically produce a (CG)WH space from $Y$ using the *weak-Hausdorffification* functor:

> Let $q:\mathsf{CG}\to\mathsf{CGWH}$ be the weak-Hausdorffification. That is, for a space $Y$, let $R\subseteq Y\times Y$ be the minimal closed equivalence relation. *Note: $Y\times Y$ is here given the product topology of the category $\mathsf{CG}$, i.e. we have “$k$-ified” the usual product by adjoining all complements of $k$-closed sets to the topology.* $R$ induces a relation $\sim$ on $Y$: define $q(Y)$ to be the quotient space $Y/_{\sim}$. It can be shown that $q(Y)$ is indeed always a WH space on the proviso $Y$ is CG (and it can be shown that $q$ is functorial).

We know $X\times X$ is compact, hence CG, and by the tube lemmas we know both projections $\pi_{1,2}:X\times X\to X$ are closed maps. To compute $q(X)$, I note that $X\times X$ is its own $k$-ification and accordingly we only seek closed equivalences $E$ to be closed in the usual product topology. $\pi_{1,2}(E)$ must also be closed in $X$, which is true iff. $E$’s projections are finite sets, or the whole space. But $E$ must contain $(x,x)$ for $x\in X$ and its projections cannot be finite. Therefore, the only such $E$ is $X\times X$. We conclude that $q(X)$ is the one-point space: in particular, $q(X)\neq X$. Because it can be shown that $q(Y)=Y$ for any CGWH space $Y$, this is proof that $X$ is not a weak-Hausdorff space.

*The question.* The above proof is quite abstract. Is it possible to exhibit a counterexample, i.e. to find a compact Hausdorff $K$ and a continuous $\nu:K\to X$ with $\nu(K)$ not closed? Such a $K$ would have to be infinite. The only nice infinite compact spaces that come to mind are the friendly and familiar compact Euclidean subspaces, but as the only continuous functions $\nu:[0,1]\to X$ are constant these examples don’t do the job. Indeed, no continuum $K$ has any non-constant map to $X$: any counterexample is necessarily disconnected. In fact, any counterexample must be totally disconnected, I’m fairly certain (I use the Sierpinski continuum theorem). We also can’t fiddle with the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta\Bbb N$ for examples since $X$ is certainly not Hausdorff, so the universal property can’t be exploited.

Moreover, I actually started writing this question under the belief $X$ *is* WH. I thought I’d found a good example of a not-Hausdorff-yet-WH space; sadly not. Could someone point me to nice examples of the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\mathbb N$ equipped with discrete topology, and let $\nu:K\to X$ be any injection. Then $X$ will be continuous - indeed, by injectivity the preimage of any cofinite subset will be cofinite, and all cofinite subsets of $K$ are open. But we can easily set $\nu$ up so that $\nu(K)$ is not closed - just inject it onto a proper subset of $X$.

Comment: Do you know of a WH space which isn’t Hausdorff?

Comment: @FShrike I think a line with a doubled origin should be WH.

Comment: Referencing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709777/815585) line with two origins, consider $K=[-1,1]$ and: $$\nu(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\neq0\\\{p\}&x=0\end{cases}$$I think $\nu$ is continuous but $\nu(K)$ isn’t closed. Its complement isn’t open at $\{q\}$.

Comment: @FShrike That was silly, of course you are right. You can find some actual examples here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/88420/30186

Comment: Ah, thanks. It seems I needed to look at the cocountable case for an example.